# Complex CSS selector having many descendant

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select `h3` and `view-grouping-header` class which resides under `menu-publications` parent. Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

In the above image, I want to select all `<h3>` and `2017` or `2016` or `2015` elements. Below is the CSS:

```
.menu-publications h3{
    background-color: red;
}
.menu-publications > .view-grouping-header{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I am not able to select `view-grouping-header`. Please see the JS-Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jz9Lxejp/).

Comment: remove the `>` - it means direct child (which grouping header is not)

Answer (score 2):

The correct selector is `.menu-publications .view-grouping-header`

```
.menu-publications h3 {
     background-color: red;
}
.menu-publications .view-grouping-header {
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

The `element > element` selector is used to select elements with a specific **parent**. Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, will not br selected.

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
.menu-publications .view-grouping-header{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

without the `>`- it's not a direct child